# How to load images with high Res in UIscrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Can anybody tell me how to load or set images with high  resolutions in UIScrollVIew .
I am getting memory warning and app is getting crashed without any stack trace.
    Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Define high res please.

Comment: How many images do u load at once?

Comment: 3 images at a time .. still app gets crash on device but works in simulator.

Answer (score 3):

I was also working on an app which had `UIScrollView` and had to request for High Resolution Images. The thing is, you should first check the size of the images being downloaded. Lets say, if the image size is more than 10MB, then it would be difficult for your app to survive with such a heavy load.

You can consider the following methodologies.

1.Download your images and compress them.

2.At a particular instance of time, there is no need to populate your Scroll Views array with all the images at once, instead try to have only three images,i.e

1.The current one which is being shown.

2.The previous one.

3.and the image next to the current one.

You can also take help from the link
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: Thank you vaibhav_15 .. 
I got a method to reduce the image resolution.
'code'
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    return newImage;
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use the concept of lazy loading. As you said you used UIScrollView that's mean you have lot's of images and I guess you show them one by one or two or three at a time. Load only that images which are visible to the user. One more thing you have to maintain that is when user swipe to next image or next branch of images that's mean next image(s) that's are going to visible to the user. At that time before load the new images release all the previously loaded images from memory. I hope it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create multiple `UIImageView` of high resolution image inside `UIScrollView`, then it will create memory warning and application will crash.

I will suggest you to try reusable `UIImageView` , like create 3 `UIImageView` and replace images in it.

Try circular scrollview.[link](http://code4app.net/ios/circularly-scrolling-view/5052e6a26803fa4a0c000003) or [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)